# installing elementary os on VM (windows host) with a bootable USB drive

Tags: microsoft-windows, install

I've downloaded elementary OS ISO file some time ago and created a bootable USB drive.
Now I cannot longer locate the original ISO file but would like to install elementary OS on a VM on a windows host. all the docs I found show the step by step using the iso file (which I no longer have)

can I use the bootable USB drive instead of the ISO file to install elementary OS on a VM ?
how?

Comment: What prevents you from downloading the .iso a second time?

Comment: In Virtual Box you do not use the bootable usb drive to install the system.
https://www.instructables.com/How-to-install-Linux-on-your-Windows/

Comment: @KGIII could not find a "recover iso" option on elementary site - trying to see if there is a way to avoid purchasing the OS a second time first

Comment: @Sysadmin that is why I asked the question: I do not have the ISO file anymore and can't complete the step by step described in the link

Comment: Download the ISO from the Elementary OS website. https://elementary.io/docs/installation#download-elementary-os

Comment: Just download it again. Enter a custom amount, make it zero, and it doesn't cost you anything to download it a second time.